# Regular Expression : Multiline check problem

Tags: java, regex, multiline

Hello i have problem with this regexp

```
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 1/49
 description Uplink
 no ip address
 switchport
 no shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 1/50
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet 1/51
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
```

i tried this regexp (interface) ((.*\s.*)+) but it is not working becuse it match "interface" and the rest of text

I need to catch in first group "interface" and in the second i need all until first occur of "!"
so for example:
first group:

```
interface
```

second group:

```
TenGigabitEthernet 1/51
 no ip address
 shutdown
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(interface)\s+([^!]+)
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hMnDB/2)

Comment: `(interface)` is the first group, `\s` - space, `[^!]` - every single character except then `!`, so it will catch untill it, `+` - 1 or more of this last char. and this is the second group.

Comment: If this answer was good for you - please eccept it, by mark V.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`(interface)\s*([^!]+) /g`

The first group captures the hard-coded `interface`. The second group captures everything other than `!`, by skipping the leading whitespaces, if any. The global flag `/g` ensures all matches.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ18EF/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the content itself can contain a `!`, you could check for a `!` at the start of the line and repeat matching all lines until you encounter a `!` at the start.

```
^(interface)\s*(.*(?:\n(?!!).*)*)
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^(interface)\\s*(.*(?:\\n(?!!).*)*)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcqKHn/1)